# Change WizardForm.TasksList offset

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, wizard

When I change `WizardForm.TasksList.Offset` to 20, the result looks like this:

http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/5968/taskslist1.png

When I change it to 120, it looks like this:

http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/7863/taskslist2.png

The problem is, I need it 120, but I don't want any space between the *checkbox* and it's *label*.
You can see that with offset 120 it looks just awful, because of that space. I want the space to appear only at the left side, not in the middle. Is there any way to accomplish that?

It actually looks like a bug to me, because offsetting on both sides of the "checkbox square" just doesn't make any sense. Or does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to Jordan Russell](http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=25269&group=jrsoftware.innosetup.code#25269) (author of Inno Setup), this is not possible.

Comment: "According to Jordan Russel" link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of WizardForm.TasksList.Offset, does setting WizardForm.TasksList.Left := 120; work for your needs?
Seems to move the checkbox over but not affect spacing otherwise.

Comment: It would move the checkboxes, but also the "headings". By headings I mean "Additional icons:" and "Advanced:". I need these headings to stay in place.